# How do I cast from an Object[] to another array type?

Tags: java, classcastexception

I have a generic (I'm not too sure if that's the correct terminology..) method that adds an object to the an array.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T>T[] appendArray(T[] a, T b)
{
    T[] temp = (T[])new Object[a.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, temp, 0, a.length);
    temp[a.length] = b;
    return temp;
}
```

In Eclipse, this code gives me no errors, no warnings (except for the suppressed "unchecked" warning), and, it seems to me, that this should work.. However, when I attempt to call this method with something such as..

```
Integer[] a=new Integer[]{1,2,3};
Integer b=4;
a = appendArray(a, b);
```

It gives me a `ClassCastException` on, in this case, line 3 of the 2nd snippet of code I posted. The error says, `[Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Integer;` I neither see, nor understand why it would be doing this.. I mean, I'm using generics, so why would it there be an `Object[]` other than the one which I cast to type `T` during instantiation? And if it is the one at line number 4 (in the 1st bit of code, of course), why isn't the exception being thrown there rather than at line 3 of the 2nd bit of code?

Comment: Why exactly was this downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `System.arraycopy`, use [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28U%5B%5D,%20int,%20java.lang.Class%29), which instantiates the array as the generic type.

```
public static <T> T[] appendArray(T[] a, T b) {
    T[] temp = (T[]) Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length + 1, a.getClass());
    temp[a.length] = b;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Technically, it does not **cast** the array. It uses the prototype (well, class information) to create an array of the proper type.

Answer (score 2):

You **can't** cast an array to a different array.

Arrays *do* have a value type. This is what `[Ljava.lang.Integer;` says: an array of Integers. And that is an incompatible type to an array of objects.

Have you noticed that all the java collections classes use `Object[]`? The reason is that this is the array type they are sure they can store their data in.

Also notice how the `toArray` method looks like. It *needs to know* the type of array you want to get out. It cannot guess the type right from the generics; essentially you need a **prototype** object, and you then need to create an array of the proper type.

Comment: But, other than `(T[])new Object[a.length + 1]`, there shouldn't be any casting anyway.. So, why isn't the error being thrown there rather than where it is?

Comment: There is no `T[]` type. It doesn't exist. The cast is incorrect, as it will in his case *NOT* make this an `Integer[]`, but it *will* remain a `Object[]` typed array. Note that `(T[])` is by type erasure a cast to `Object[]`, not `Integer[]`.

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it doesn't answer the question correctly.  As is evident from other answers, there are several ways to fix the OP's code in order to run without throwing an exception.

Comment: @Vulcan none of these performs a **cast** on the arrays. They work around this by creating an array of the proper type right away.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood what your answer was saying wasn't possible.  If you edit your answer, I can remove the downvote.

Comment: Thanks. I gave you a +1, as your answer contains a code snippet more helpful than my rather "language theoretical" answer.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have covered how to rewrite the code to work, but the second half of your question is still there, so:

You seem to misunderstand fundamentally what a cast is.  It does not change the real type of anything.  It tells the compiler "Hey, pretend this reference of type X is actually a Y, trust me, I know."

`Integer i = (Integer) new Object();`

That doesn't cause an `Object` to become an `Integer`!  It throws an error at runtime when JVM figures out that you lied to the compiler.

The reason the error happens later than you expect in your example is that 'T' is a compile-time-only concept in java.  For runtime purposes you can replace every 'T' with `Object`.

As part of the Type Erasure process, code that checks to see if the claim you are making that this method returns an `Integer[]` gets put in at the point where your method returns and tries to make an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Generics and arrays don't mix!

There is a way around it. You can use the special [`Array.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int%29) method to create an array object with the specific component type:

```
public static <T> T[] appendArray(T[] a, T b) {
    T[] temp = (T[]) Array.newInstance(b.getClass(), a.length + 1);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, temp, 0, a.length);
    temp[a.length] = b;
    return temp;
}
```

This code does not throw any errors when called:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] a = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    Integer b = 4;
    a = appendArray(a, b);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: `Arrays.copyOf` basically combines `Array.newInstance` and `System.arraycopy`.

Comment: @Vulcan Yeah that's why I +1 your answer. I didn't know about `copyOf()` - nice :)

Comment: when you use Array.newInstance, you can pass it a.getClass().getComponentType() instead of b.getClass().  This ensures you have the same output array type (in case b is some subclass and the array is of a superclass type).

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `ArrayList` with generic a generic type of `T` and get it as an array.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T>T[] appendArray(T[] a, T b)
{
    T[] temp = new ArrayList<T>(Arrays.asList(a)).toArray(a);
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, temp, 0, a.length);
    temp[a.length-1] = b;
    return temp;
}
```